# JQuery mouseleave function errors with css

Tags: javascript, jquery

There's a proplem that's no sense in JQuery. The problem is while mouseover on button it's repeat fade in and out.
 [in this gif you can see](https://gph.is/2K5cnpy)

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
        <img src="img.jpg" class="img">
        <a href="" class="bio">Biography</a>
        <ul>
            <li><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i><span>Aysha Mamedi</span></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i><span>New York</span></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-star-of-life"></i><span>Software Engineer</span></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-hourglass-start"></i><span>20</span></li>
            <li><i class="fas fa-file-signature"></i><span>aysha@mamedi.com</span></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box .bio {
        position: absolute;
        top: 400px;
        left: 20px;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        background-color: rgba(250,250,250, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
        border-radius: 5px;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .box .bio:hover {
        background-color: transparent;
    }
```

**Script(Jquery)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("img.img").hover(function(){
            $("a.bio").css("display","inline");
        });
        $("img.img").mouseleave(function(){
            $("a.bio").css("display","none");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need help immediately. If you have any idea please tell me. I'm new in web deving.
Need to be perfect in short time. and I have language probs also. Thanks.

Comment: please add whole of your code.

Comment: I'll do in a few secs

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Try to give only class name in jquery selector like $('.img') instead of $('img.img')

Answer (score 0):

It happens because when you hover the `a.bio` element (which is not a child of the image) the `mouseleave` is triggered.

You can wrap the image and this element inside a `div`, and set the events on the div.

Comment: no buddy. changed and run it again but same result.

Comment: try adding the `a` element to the event handlers - $("img.img, a.bio"). Any change?

Comment: $("img.img, a.bio").hover(...);          $("img.img, a.bio").mouseleave(...);

Comment: Great. If so, my previous solution (to wrap them inside a div) should also work. maybe you should give it another try, because it's a better solution.